# Zend_Mail sent email is treated as SPAM

Tags: php, zend-framework, email-spam, zend-mail

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I am sending an email using the Zend_Mail class like this:

```
$message = <<<STR
You have a new invoice!

Sign in to your clientarea to see it.

Best regards,

Company name
STR;

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText($message);
$mail->setFrom('billing@company.com', 'Company.com');
$mail->addTo('client@email.com', 'Client Name');
$mail->setSubject('You have a new invoice!');
$mail->send();
```

It is received as a spam though. There are other applications such as Webmin on my server and emails they send is not treated as SPAM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP:How to avoid a system generated email going into spam?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800898/phphow-to-avoid-a-system-generated-email-going-into-spam)

Comment: See also the linked questions in that duplicate

Comment: Adding Reply-To header solved the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved this by adding these lines:

```
$mail->setReplyTo('contact@company.com', 'Company');
$mail->addHeader('MIME-Version', '1.0');
$mail->addHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', '8bit');
$mail->addHeader('X-Mailer:', 'PHP/'.phpversion());
```

The critical line seems to be adding Reply-To header. Without that it would always go to SPAM. Once I set the Reply-To header email clients stopped treating it as spam.

Comment: What is the `from` header set to now?

Comment: billing@company.com, reply to is contact@company.com.